# Ionic lab displays only black screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I made a menu based starter app with ionic. When I run the app with `ionic serve` everything is working fine. When I run `ionic serve --lab` the "lab" is just displaying a black screen. I tried removing the lab and installing it again. Now I still see a black display but I am getting an error message saying:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (p-5700d57c.system.js, line 0)

[Error] Refused to execute http://localhost:8200/build/p-5700d57c.system.js as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.

When I try to run the app native on a device the result is the same as with the lab.

Answer (score 0):

go to

project-folder/node_modules/@ionic/lab/www/build/app

And *rename* app.rjnahnnl.js file to app.jcrhwwkm.js